# Ошибка типизации свойства при объявлении [] | string[] или [] | Array<string> в Vuex

Tags: typescript

Я объявил интерфейс:

```
export interface ApplicationState extends RootState {
  messages: [] | string[];
}
```

Я говорю, что моё свойство должно быть либо пустым массивом, либо массивом строк. Но в мутации я получаю ошибку:

```
[MutationTypes.APPEND_MESSAGES](state: ApplicationState, payload: string): void {
  state.messages.push(payload);
},
```

> TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

Но если я убирая `[] |`, то всё ок. В чём я ошибаюсь или что не понимаю?

Окружение:

**Typescript**: `3.9.7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете делать push в тип `[]` который может быть **только** пустым массивом, отсюда и ошибка.

Обычно просто используют `string[]`.

Если вам нужно напоминание о том что элемента массива может не быть, то попробуйте:

`Array<string | undefined>`

Или

`;(state.messages as string[]).push(payload)`

Или просто держите в голове, что state.messages[1] может быть `undefined`

Comment: `Вы не можете делать push в тип [] который может быть только пустым массивом, отсюда и ошибка.` - почему не могу?  Есть объяснение или документация?

Comment: во всех примерах обычно встречается `any[]` но никогда `[]`, с недавнего времени можно писать так `unknown[]`. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/EYQwJgXABA3gUFRUAuBPADgUygEnQJwHt0BnKAXigG0BdBJAMwFcA7AY2QEtCWoBHABQA6EQWIloeIqQCUsKAF96iQQEYANFABMmgMxyA9AagBRAB5YOmMFAAMUEPgDmTALaYWyEpuBNkUJ0J-XSEBLQBWcIAWGTglQMJIWGUUDGwpcQooVgBrFkIAdxZaFOZ2Lh5+YVFpCVwxWXklJCqNbT1YpSA

Comment: наверное, консткуция вида `[]` воспринимается как tule `[string, number, ...]`

Comment: `Array<>` - "Generic type 'Array<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).(2314)"

Comment: недостаток `any[]` что он будет перекрывать, так что правильнее использовать `unknown[] | string[]` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/EYQwJgXABA3gUFRUAuBPADgUygEnQJwHt0BnKAXigG0BdBJAMwFcA7AY2QEtCWoBHABQA6EQWIloeIqQCUsKAF96iQQEYANFABMmgMxyA9AagBRAB5YOmMFAAMUEPgDmTALaYWyEpuBNkUJ0J-XSEBLQBWcIAWGTglQMJIWGUUDGwpcQooVgBrFkIAdxZaFOZ2Lh5+YVFpCVwxWWSkZqg2HhJ-Pj4shpIqVRooIzaWDv4+aFz8opTmzgYoAU4SAGVkfE4WJwEumTl4FsPW9s6+AqyuoeMRsa6C6DWNrdmkJWa3pDVNHSh9OLg4GUONxeMtHptthMHCxUDJoN1llBwVsmkgjFAACoAeQAIljoGwABaYNg5FL4TDIJj4XjrJiYOJAA

Comment: @doox911 потому что пустой массив не может содержать элементов. Если вы объявите x: [], то вы не можете сделать x.push(1), так как массив может быть только пустым, вы сами его так объявили. Объявление массива как x: [] | string[] тоже не сработают, так как один из типов - это пустой массив и вы не можете делать пуш в массив один из типов которого может быть пустым пока не скажите тс что это массив стринг как показано в примере ;(state.messages as string[]).push(payload)

Comment: Ничего не понял. Я же говорю `TS`, что свойство может быть либо пустым массивом, либо массивом с строками. Мне кажется это баг или  есть какое-то  соглашение?

Comment: @doox911 вы говорите что переменная может быть любого из двух типов и как тогда вы можете делать пуш если одним из типов может быть пустой массив? Пушить в пустой массив нельзя.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо. Я думал, что логика другая. `TS`  смотрит, пустой массив, ага свойство может быть пустым массивом(определили), а в другом месте мы туда что-то пушим и `TS` смотрит, ага это не пустой массив есть ли у него другие типы и видит, что массив может быть не пустым, но содержать только элементы с типом строка и не выдаёт ошибки. А получается, что `TS`как-то примитивно проверяет...